# Simple way to get distinct column names in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Following is the query I am running in mysql which is working fine-

```
SELECT * 
FROM `events` e 
LEFT JOIN venues v 
ON e.venue_id = v.id 
WHERE e.artist_id = 16
```

In my event and artist table I have some common naming attributes like `id` , `lat`, `long` etc

So on getting the resultant output from the query I need to do something like this to make id, lat, long distinguish is to specify all column names with respect to its table-

```
SELECT e.id as e_id, v.id as v_id .........AND LOT MORE
FROM `events` e 
LEFT JOIN venues v 
ON e.venue_id = v.id 
WHERE e.artist_id = 16
```

So you see for only 3-4 things I need to write a lot instead of simple `*` ...so being from the lazy race of developers, I am looking for someway to shorten this instead of writing and specifying everything in `SELECT ......`.

Please let me know if there is a way with which I can make it short.

Comment: Don't be lazy. Simples.

Comment: In this I'd suggest getting over being lazy.  You could loop through the column names and build a sql string and execute it dynamically, but that makes it hard to write other code against.  Best to just type it out.. build a macro or something if its really that bad.

Comment: @Strawberry okk .it means no simple way rather than specifying all columns corresponding to its table :(

Comment: Depending on the overlap, you could do `e.*, ...` if you need all the common ones from e, and not from v, but that's still not very nice. Select the columns you need - databases often change over time. If you don't like writing SQL then use an ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automatically enumerate columns in a way similar to this:

```
$cols = [];

$stmt = $db->exec("SHOW COLUMNS FROM events");
foreach($stmt as $r)
    $cols []= "e.{r['Field']} as e_{r['Field']}";

// the same for the second table, then

$cols = implode(',', $cols);

"SELECT $cols FROM ..."
```

If you're doing many queries like this, you can cache generated column lists somewhere to avoid excessive "SHOW COLUMNS" queries (although those are very fast).